# Getting all selected val()'s from a multiselect container per it's own click:event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, multi-select

Per the following [multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) I need to grab the selected values that are selected from many multidropdowns on one page.  I have a generic event handler setup where if a selection is clicked on any of the multiselect on the page it fires a common event.  Two problems/questions:

1) How can I tell what muliselect (#Name) the event came from?
2) How can I grab the .val()'s from  the multiselect click function if the event is from the same container?

```
// generic event for all multiselect
$("select").multiselect({
    click: function (event, ui) {
        // 1 - What multiselect container?
        // 2- Get the list of selected values
        var vals = $('#CNames').val();  // This doesn't work if the event was fired from #CNames..null.
        var vals = $('#CAreas').val();  // This works if the event came from #CNames.
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Every time a user checks a new selection, you want to build a list with all the values from both multiselect boxes?  Or do you want to do something simpler, like detect which check box was checked?

Comment: @rkw: I want to grab all selected items in every multiselect when any multiselect item is clicked and then pass each multiselects (selected) values back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get the id of the select that was clicked with

```
var name = $(this).attr('id');
```

and the values of all the selects with

```
var values = [];
$('select').each(function() {
    $.merge(values, $(this).val());
});
```

or the current select with

```
var values = $(this).val();
```

Comment: Thx for the reply. The 1st one works getting the container id.  The 2nd doesn't return and the 3rd comes back with null (when called within $("select").multiselect({
    click: function (event, ui) {...});

Answer (score 1):

The code from aliz should work.  Try binding them all the way the documentation shows:

```
$("select").bind("multiselectclick", function(event, ui){
    var values = [];
    $('select').each(function() {
        $.merge(values, $(this).val());
    }
    alert(values);
});
```